# Missing management console for Symantec Antivirus, Corporate Edition

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, anti-virus, symantec

I work for a small (80 employees) non-profit organization.  We have a Windows network with a domain.  The file server is running Server 2003.

A vendor recently installed Symantec Antivirus, Corporate Edition, ver. 10.1.8.8000.

It used to be the case that when I logged in to the file server as administrator, I would see an icon on the desktop that took me to the management console for the antivirus software.  I could check logs, statuses of client machines, set policies, etc.

That icon is now missing, and I can't find anything relevant under the "Start" menu.  There is an entry for Symantec Antivirus, but that only gives me the panel for the client process, not the overall management console for the whole network.

I don't want to call the vendor back to fix this (I'm baffled how we lost the icon in the first place).

Can someone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The management console is normally installed at this location. You might alos search for Symantec System Center.msc to see if the installer did something unusual

"C:\Program Files\Symantec\Symantec System Center\Symantec System Center.msc"

Bear in mind that if they applied a password, you will need to know it to manage the clients.  However, there is a tool to reset a lost password.

Finally, do you have the disks?  You can just do an install.  It is really straight forward.  If you have maintenance with Symantec, you can also download the media

Comment: OK, thanks so much for the quick answer.  The problem was solved.